# How I can detect transactions submitted on bitcoin from L2 Lightening network?

Tags: lightning-network

I want to identify transactions submitted from L2 on the Bitcoin blockchain. How I can find these transactions?

For example, in the Lightening network, do transactions wait in Mempool? If not, how the lightning is connected to the Bitcoin blockchain?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> **how the lightning is connected to the Bitcoin blockchain?**

When a Lightning channel is opened or closed, there is a corresponding transaction on the Bitcoin Blockchain. From what I've read, the opening transaction involves a 2 of 2 multisig output. It can't be distinguished from similar outputs created for reasons other than opening lightning channels.

In between those events there would typically be a large number of lightning transactions, using Lightning channels, that leave no trace in the Bitcoin Blockchain.

---

Useful References

- https://voltage.cloud/blog/lightning-network-faq/what-do-open-channel-transactions-look-like-on-chain/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is how I can identify opened and closed transactions confirmed in Bitcoin blockchain?

Comment: The channel opening and channel closing transactions will be among those involving 2 of 2 multisig.